# How to fix the error message in the Google Play Market about the ads library that was already removed?

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, admob, google-developers-console

I use React Native and try to update my app on Play Market. However, I can’t pass the auto-moderation and get the following error:

*The developer of Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads) added the following note to SDK version 19.8.0:
This version is scheduled to sunset on June 30th 2023. See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/deprecation for more information.
You must upgrade to a newer version before you can publish a new release to production.*

I can’t understand why I get this message, taking into account the fact that I’ve already set in Gradle `implementation com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0`. and I’ve performed the following commands:

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache  
rm -rf ~/.gradle  
watchman watch-del-all   
yarn cache clean   
rm -rf node_modules/
```

My app's Gradle dependencies look like this:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native" version {
    strictly "0.62.2"
}
implementation 'org.chromium:v8-android:+'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0'
```

Locally everything runs correctly. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Here is a list of the Android dependencies: https://github.com/etirskih/android-app-dependencies/blob/main/dependens.txt

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please attach a list of Android dependencies using these commands:

`cd android
./gradlew app:dependencies  `

Comment: @VasylNahuliak thanks for your message! Since there's a limit for characters in the question, I published the list of dependencies here: https://github.com/etirskih/android-app-dependencies/blob/main/dependens.txt. I appreciate it if you check and try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a play-services-ads-lite library in your app's dependencies. So, I recommend adding implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:20.0.0' to your app's gradle build.